# Traducción para "Good Sport"

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término

En inglés cuando se usa "*good sport*" a modo de adjetivo se califica a una persona de saber afrontar una situación algo molesta. Según [*wiktionary*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/good_sport) un "good sport" es

> someone who exhibits polite behaviour even or especially when things go wrong
>
> someone who can take a joke

Por ejemplo, digamos que vas a ver un monólogo de comedia o un truco de magia, y resulta que el artista elige a alguien del público (tú) y hace unos cuántos chistes a tu costa. Si lo tomas con humor y entiendes que es por la situación y no es nada personal (le podría haber tocado igualmente a otro) y te ríes y disfrutas, siguiendo las bromas, estás siendo un *good sport*.

O digamos que vas al cine pero le toca elegir a tu pareja, quien elige un peli que para ti es un aburrimiento total, pero como entiendes que es "su turno" lo afrontas "con deportividad" y un poco de resignación. Ya te tocará "tu turno".

O que el próximo sábado, en lugar de hacer lo que tú quieres y disfrutar de tu tiempo libre te toca ir a comer a casa de tus suegros, pero vas igualmente sin pasar todo el día "*amargao*" y dando evidentes muestras de estar a disgusto, y teniendo un trato agradable con todos (este ejemplo suponiendo claro que no te guste ir. Si tus suegros te caen bien o cocinan de maravilla, pues lo mismo hasta estás deseando ir y no cuenta como ser un *good sport*... :-) )

Desde luego la paciencia es un rasgo clave, pero para traducir el término correctamente hace falta algo más que calificar a alguien de `paciente` ya que un *good sport* además no se queja mucho y acepta la situación con carácter afable.

¿Cuál es la mejor manera de traducir "*good sport*"?

Comment: No tengo una sola palabra para *good sport* o *sportsmanship*.  En tus ejemplos, diría cosas así: Lo toma con calma, acepta que no es su turno, no se exalta, no es quisquilloso, no lo toma personalmente, tiene carácter tranquilo, accede de buena gana, es una persona calmada.  Linguee me dió: tiene el temperamento apacible, tiene trato campechano con sus compañeros, tiene carácter plácido.

Comment: A la medalla _Sportmanship_ en [es.so] la tradujeron por [_Espíritu deportivo_](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/63/sportsmanship).

Comment: Me gustan todas las sugerencias de @aparente001 mucho más que la respuesta de Carlos. Aparente001 deberías convertir tu comentario en respuesta.

Comment: En Colombia se dice que "es de lavar y planchar" o que "está pa'las que sea" pero en español "estándar" me quedo con las definiciones de @aparente001

Comment: Es netamente una cuestión de contexto.  En una competencia, *a good sport person* es un *buen perdedor.*  Otra expresión muy coloquial es *bancársela* o simplemente *se la bancó.*

Answer (score 5):

Puedes usar el verbo "encajar":

> **[encajar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=EwwHYTQ)**
>
> 5. tr. Recibir, soportar sin gran quebranto golpes, un resultado o tanteo adverso, etc.

Como lo que estás buscando es un calificativo para la persona, puedes decir ***que sabe encajar***, como en el siguiente ejemplo del CORDE:

> *Bueno, pues el cipote todavía porfiaba que no sabía encajar una broma y que si tal, y que venía haciendo de Neptuno desde que nació y nunca le ocurrió una cosa así.*
>
> Miguel Delibes, "Diario de un emigrante", 1958 (España).

En el caso del cine puedes decir que "supo encajar una derrota" (le tocaba decidir a ella, otra vez será), en el caso de la visita a la suegra puedes decir que "supo encajar el mal trago", en el caso de los chistes a costa de uno puedes decir que "los supo encajar con humor", etc.

Comment: Aunque esto no invalida la respuesta, hago notar que en Argentina *encajar un golpe* es expresión ditransitiva y significa "golpear" (vale también para *encajar una patada*, etc.). Es decir, casi exactamente lo opuesto que en estos ejemplos.

Answer (score 5):

En casos así, según el contexto, yo usaría:

- "**Tomarse las cosas con deportividad**": pude usarse, como ya has apuntado, en contextos que impliquen competitividad o enfrentamiento: perder en un juego, perder en una discusión (tu ejemplo del cine), ser objeto de una broma ligera o sin importancia, aceptar que a veces hay que ceder...
- "**Tomarse las cosas con filosofía**": para situaciones mas relacionadas con los avatares de la vida, desgracias, *setbacks* y demás.  Cuando cierra tu empresa, cuando se es el objeto de burlas serias, cuando te deniegan la beca que esperabas, cuando te dejan por otra persona... Usar "deportividad" en esos contextos podría banalizar la situación mas allá de lo deseable. Entonces, una expresión común es la que tira de la 5ª acepción de [filosofía](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Hw9B3HA): `Fortaleza o serenidad de ánimo para soportar las vicisitudes de la vida`.

Un adjetivo concreto... En muchos diccionarios de sinónimos aparece "nobleza" como sinónimo de "deportividad". Podrías entonces usar "**noble**":

> Sabe aguantar una broma y nunca se toma las cosas a mal. Es una persona muy **noble**.

Answer (score 4):

No tengo una sola palabra para *good sport* o *sportsmanship*.

En tus ejemplos, diría cosas así:

- Lo toma con calma
- Acepta que no es su turno
- No se exalta
- No es quisquilloso
- No lo toma personalmente
- Tiene carácter tranquilo
- Accede de buena gana
- Es una persona calmada.

Linguee me dio:

- tiene el temperamento apacible
- tiene trato campechano con sus compañeros
- Tiene carácter plácido.

Pero hay más formas de expresarlo.  Esta lista no está completa.

Answer (score 3):

Mi abuelita diría: "ese chiquillo tiene **presencia de ánimo**". Significa que no te quiebras en situaciones difíciles, y creo que se acerca más a *aplomo* o *temple* que a *espíritu deportivo*, pero lo aporto igual.

Es una frase que se usa en Chile, más bien entre personas mayores.

Comment: Por Colombia también la he oído de igual forma de personas mayores.

Answer (score 2):

Y que tal [Temple](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ZQyCw3M)

> 6. m. Fortaleza enérgica y valentía serena para afrontar las dificultades y los riesgos.

Aquí en México se usa la expresión:

> Tiene temple de acero