# Cómo traducir "trouper" al español?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término

En inglés el término "trouper" (a veces visto también como "trooper", que en un homónimo que define a [un tipo de policía o de policía montada](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/trooper)) se usa para describir a alguien que puede aguantar grandes adversidades o dificultades.

> **Trouper**
>
> a person who deals with and persists through difficulty or hardship without complaint <sub>[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/trouper)</sub>
>
> **Trooper** <sub>[onlineslangdictionary.com](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/trooper)</sub>
>
> one who handles adversity well
>
> Courageous, persistent person.
>
> One who does not give up in the face of adversity.
>
> Somebody who does something strenuous or tedious for a long period of time without complaining.  <sub>[urbandictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=trooper)</sub>

Por ejemplo:

> Yeah, he was a **trooper**, man. He waited in line 4 hours to get tickets.

Y otros ejemplos de *[trouper](https://grammarpartyblog.com/2012/10/03/trooper-vs-trouper/)*

> - A student who has a bad cold and still shows up to take the big test is a trouper.
> - A runner who stubs his toe in the middle of a marathon and keeps running is a trouper.
> - A dancer who falls in the middle of her big solo and continues on with the routine is a trouper.
> - A person who is fighting a serious illness is a trouper.

Lo primero que puede venir a la cabeza es `persistente`, pero alguien calificado como *trouper* no es solo alguien que se mantiene firme o aguanta esas dificultades. Alguien que las realiza sin quejarse (como un [*good sport*](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/20923/5481), aunque este término se usa en contextos algo distintos) puede ser también calificado como un *trouper*.

Qué término podría usarse entonces para definir a alguien que persiste ante las dificultades y supera los obstáculos sin quejarse en exceso?

Comment: No lo pongo como respuesta porque solo aplica para una parte de Colombia pero aquí tenemos una que es [berraco](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/17543/11102) que aplicar 100%

Answer (score 4):

Yo optaría por las siguientes palabras:

- [Campeón](http://dle.rae.es/?id=70HDbFA), en su segunda acepción de la RAE: Persona que defiende esforzadamente una causa o doctrina.
- [Luchador](http://dle.rae.es/?id=NeQcg1d), en su primera acepción: Tenaz en el esfuerzo para sacar adelante su propósito.

Personalmente, noto una pequeña diferencia entre ambas: "campeón" me resulta un poco más familiar que "luchador", que percibo como más formal.

Quizás no sean tan vistosas como "trouper" en inglés, son mucho más literales, y puede que carezcan de algún matiz de la original, pero yo creo que se adaptan bastante bien a los ejemplos que propones:

- Qué campeón, aguantó cuatro horas en la cola a pesar del diluvio.
- A pesar del resfriado, el estudiante fue a clase, qué campeón.
- El corredor se rompió un dedo del pie durante la carrera y aun así continuó, es un luchador/campeón.

Comment: Campeón es la que yo también usaría +1

Answer (score 0):

*Trooper* es incorrecto.  *Trouper* viene de los actores que siguen con el espectáculo a pesar de varios, o muchos, contratiempos.

La traducción va a depender del contexto, por ejemplo:

> Juanito was a great patient, a real trouper throughout the whole procedure.
>
> Juanito puso mucho de su parte, fue un buen paciente durante todo el procedimiento.
>
> The band members were real troupers.  They kept playing and gave a great show despite the downpour.
>
> Los integrantes de la banda son a todo dar.  Siguieron tocando y montaron un buen espectáculo, a pesar del aguacero.

*Hubiera preferido ver un ejemplo específico donde te gustaría tener un equivalente de "trouper".*

Answer (score -1):

He obtenido tambien la traducción de trouper como perturbador.
Sinónimo de disturbing.
Por ejemplo: Super trouper. Super perturador.

Pero en la canción de Abba es el foco que ilumina al actor

Comment: Hola, gracias por la respuesta. Entra en contradicción con las otras respuetas, ¿podrías aportar referencias que sustenten tu hipótesis? Dale a [edit] para añadirlas, ¡gracias!